# Can't Access Sessions or Variables through pages

Tags: archives, variables, headers, session

So I'm trying to use a session to move a variable through pages. For some reason I literally cannot access anything from index.php to archive. I declare my session at the very top of my header.php like:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION))
    {
        $_SESSION['catID'] = 3;
    }
?>
```

Then I move to the archive.php which pulls in the header via `<?php get_header() ?>` and my session is suddenly gone. I try to echo it out and get nothing. Same thing happens with normal variables - like it's out of scope.

Anybody else have a similar problem or a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WordPress you need to start the session with

`if ( !session_id() ) { session_start(); }`

in order to use session variables. You can enter this code into wp-config

See http://www.frank-verhoeven.com/using-session-in-wordpress